# Why can't my rx-let bindings include `bol` or `line-start`?

Tags: regular-expressions, rx

The following works:

```lisp
(rx-let ((headers (? (or "From" "To" "Cc") ":")))
  (list "mail.amazon"  (rx bol headers anything "amazon" anything)
     ;; ("mail.amazon" "^\\(?:\\(?:Cc\\|From\\|To\\):\\)?[^z-a]amazon[^z-a]")
     ))
```

But the following fails:

```lisp
(rx-let ((headers (bol (or "From" "To" "Cc") ":")))
  (list "mail.amazon"  (rx headers anything "amazon" anything)
     ;; rx--translate-form: Unknown rx form ‘bol’
     ))
```

Why is rx-let having issues with rx forms like `bol`? I've also tried its alias, `line-start`, but the result was the same.

Comment: Each `rx-let` binds a single `rx` form to a name. `(? ...)` is a single form (`?` takes any number of `rx` forms as arguments), but `(bol ...)` is not a valid `rx` form (`bol` is an `rx` form of its own, without taking an argument list). Try `(: bol ...)`, `(seq bol ...)`, or similar instead.

Comment: It works! Make an answer out of it and I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docstring of `rx-let` describes the expected format of each binding (`^^` emphasis mine):

```
rx-let is an autoloaded Lisp macro in ‘rx.el’.

(rx-let BINDINGS BODY...)

Evaluate BODY with local BINDINGS for ‘rx’.
BINDINGS is an unevaluated list of bindings each on the form
(NAME [(ARGS...)] RX).
                  ^^
```

Note that it binds a single `RX` form to each `NAME`.

> ```el
> (rx-let ((headers (? (or "From" "To" "Cc") ":"))) ...)
> ```

This first example works because `(? ...)` is a valid `rx` form (which in turn takes other `rx` forms as arguments).

> ```el
> (rx-let ((headers (bol (or "From" "To" "Cc") ":"))) ...)
> ```

But the error message for this example is expected, since `(bol ...)` is not a valid `rx` form: `bol` is an atomic `rx` form that does not take an argument list.

The forms `bol`, `(or ...)`, and `":"` can be sequenced/wrapped as a single `rx` form using the `seq` form (alias `:`):

```el
(rx-let ((headers (seq bol (or "From" "To" "Cc") ":"))) ...)
```